# Xdebug is not working with Phpstorm

Tags: php, google-chrome, phpstorm, xdebug

I installed the xdebug using below insturctions and Xdebug was succesfully installed.
[image]

It is my phpinfo.php
[image]
[image]

Then I follow [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) intructions, I made everthing what it says.

- I started Listening for PHP Debug Connections
- I Set a breakpoint in the source code
- I added [that](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc) extension to chrome

Then I ran Chrome extension and refresh page.
[image]

It didn't happend anything.

**EDIT**
phpinfo.php shows that xdebug exist but when I test from console, I can not see my xdebug.
[image]

Do you have an idea what should I make about that. ?

thank you.

Comment: Have you turned debugging on (green bug icon in PHPStorm)?

Comment: When I click the debug button, Another window opens and This error shows "502 Bad Gateway". Bu below page says only refresh page after activate chrome extension 
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: Just adding extension is not enough. You have to click on "bug" icon to create "debug me" cookie. In any case: please provide xdebug log: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log ALSO -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Troubleshooting+PhpStorm+debugging

Comment: @LazyOne I edited my answer, An image was added below this sentence = > "Then I ran Chrome extension and refresh page. " . Do I exactly understand you ?

Comment: Yes -- all good in that regard. 1) Show **whole** xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured on that site 2) xdebug log please -- it can tell a lot.

Comment: @LazyOne I updated the question. I added three new images that two of them are about phpinfo.php and one of them is about my console output.

Comment: RE console: it may use different php installation or just different php.ini file (2nd one is more likely). To check what .ini file it uses check the header table of `phpinfo()` / `php -i` output.

Comment: @LazyOne Firstly thank you so much because I could solve the problem through link that in your comments. I think, It 2nd one is true because phpinfo() works my mamp server. Console works different private/etc/php.ini

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It was exactly my mistake.
When I was adding neccessary codes to php.ini file I missed some information.

Remote_enable, remote_host and remote_port must be exactly added.

So my final php.ini file.
[image]